# Linear Algebra - linear independence true/false question

Tags: linear-algebra

Question :

$$v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n,w\in R^n$$

These are scalars

$$x_1,\ldots,x_n$$

If this equation :

$$x_1v_1+x_2v_2+\cdots+x_nv_n=w$$

doesn't have solution therefore

$$A=\{ v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n,w\}$$

A is not linear independent?

My answer :

False.

Since $A$ has more than $R^n$ members (since $A$ has $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n,w$ members), therefore we can conclude that $A$ is linear independent, therefore the answer is false.

I'm not so sure about my answer sure I didn't use the equation has not solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're on the right track. Think of it this way - $\Bbb R^n$ is spanned by $n$ vectors, so if there are more than $n$, they cannot be independent.

Comment: I think you want to say that A is linearly dependent (because it has more than n vectors), so the statement is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the equation

$$x_1v_1+x_2v_2+\cdots+x_nv_n=w$$

Does not have a solution, then we can conclude that $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ couldn't possibly be a basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But since it has $n$ elements, it must be linearly dependent.

Comment: What if $v_1=v_2=\dots=v_n$?

Comment: In the case of $v_1=v_2=..=v_n$ A is linearly dependent since all vectors are equal therefore any vector in A $$v_i=v_1x_1+v_2x_2+...+v_nx_n+wx_m$$ since $v_1=v_2=..=v_n$ choose $x_1=x_2=...=x_n=1$, and $x_m=0$